# Two requirement were set for a function however, the reason of unsuccessful transaction displays only for one reason

Tags: contract-design

I have set two requirements for withdrawing Money;
(a) the beneficiary has to be the initiator of Smartcontract (SM) and
(b) the contract will pause if condition (a) is not met.

However, the reason of unsuccessful traction while executing the (SM) displays only one reason i.e, condition (a).

Why is that the second message which states "Contract Paused" gets displayed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;
contract selftest {
    //money trasfer
    address public Beneficiary;
    bool public Pause;
    constructor (){
        Beneficiary = msg.sender;

    }
    
    function TransferMoney() public payable{

    }
    function ContractPause(bool _paused) public {
        require(msg.sender == Beneficiary, "Beneficiary only");
        Pause = _paused ;
    }
    // Withdrawinging Money
    function WithdrawMoney(address payable _to) public {
        require(Beneficiary == msg.sender, "Trasaction Declined");
        require(Pause == false, "Contract Paused");
        _to.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because if `require` fails, it also stops and reverts, just like `assert` in other languages.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.